# The elements [keycloak.configurationfile] were left unbound

Tags: java, spring, authentication, authorization, keycloak

I have this in my props

```
keycloak.configurationFile=classpath:keycloak.json
```

Spring keycloak version is 11.0.3.

How to fix this?

```
Binding to target [Bindable@4682eba5 type = org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootProperties, value = 'provided', annotations = array<Annotation>[@org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties(ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false, prefix=keycloak, value=keycloak)]] failed:

    Property: keycloak.configurationfile
    Value: classpath:keycloak.json
    Origin: class path resource [application-local.properties] - 68:28
    Reason: The elements [keycloak.configurationfile] were left unbound.
```

Comment: Have you got any solution?, I am also facing the same. I have created custom confi class for KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver but still no luck

Comment: @Ravi, sorry, no

Comment: Have you got any solution? I am also facing the same.

Comment: no( left it....

Comment: have you tried to remove that line and put the configuration raw into the `application.properties` instead of referring to the json-file?